# Get Client IP with Python in FastCGI

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, fastcgi

What's the best practice for getting a client's IP with python3 in a FastCGI (e.g. Apache) environment?

```
import os
ip = os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Running the above code on the server just gives me this error:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'
```

Comment: Have you tried cgi.print_environ_usage() and looking for the IP address?

Comment: @ADITYA I'm getting `<H3>These environment variables could have been set:</H3> ... <LI>REMOTE_ADDR` – so I'm guessing they are not set? Do I need to tell Apache to do something first? Very new to this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try google search